# Have any Hindu acharyas commented on the amendability of Dharma Shastras?

Tags: dharma-shastras

A poster writes "This *samudrolanghana* [loss of caste due to seafaring] was made up fear so that Brahmins learned in Vedas don't move out of the country and lose the Veda sakha."

However, this is all quaint now because Hindu priests are clamoring to come to the US - not just for religious visas but citizenship. The center of Hinduism has also started shifting to the US.

Given that this *samudrolanghana* rule is not followed by many Hindus (priests included), have any Hindu acharyas commented on the amendability of dharma shastras in general?

Comment: The question is opinion based though interesting and curious.  Can rules, rituals and prescriptions of Hinduism be discarded officially as inapplicable based on modernity cannot be answere with reference to the existing puranas, smritis and sutras. It becomes subjective - extending the question further why not the same yardstick be applied to Christianity, Islam. Judaism and so on? Their scriptures Bible, Quran, etc. also contain such anomalies.

Comment: Instead you can ask - is amendment in Dharma Shāstras allowed? If yes, how?

Comment: hindu priests are "voting with their feet" as Americans say.  so the stricture against crossing the ocean is gone de facto.